# make text on half transparent overlay opaque (also alignment)

Tags: html, css

I have a basic question about text on a non-opaque overlay. Currently, I have this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdsJ9/134/). However, the word kitty is not opaque and you can see the image below. How can I make it have transparency:1 while still have the current overlay effect?

Also, how can I align the text vertically?

Thank you guys soooo much! I have been struggling with CSS for awhile.

html code:

```
<div class="bucket">
<a href="#">
<img src="http://kittybloger.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/cute-kittens-20-great-pictures-1.jpg" alt="" class="bucket"/> 
<div class="img-overlay">
    <h3>kitty</h3>
  </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.bucket {
width: 31%;
float: left;
position: relative;
margin-top: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
margin-left: 1%;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
overflow: hidden;   
}

.img-overlay h3 {
opacity: 1;
color: rgba(255,254,254,1.00);
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 100%;
}

.img-overlay {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
bottom: 0px;
top: 0px;
opacity: 0;
overflow:hidden
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
transition: opacity 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 }
.bucket:hover .img-overlay {
opacity:0.75;
filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}

.bucket img {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: So you want a solid black div over the image?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I want a black div with 0.75 transparency over the image.

Comment: Simple rule: It is not possible for an element to have a greater opacity than it's parent.

Comment: @Adam: I know what you mean is correct, but the phrasing is a little mistakable – so kindly let me rephrase it this way: It is of course possible to _set_ a greater `opacity` value – but the effect is of course that these value get _multiplied_; an element with `.9` inside an element with `.5` will result in the inner element having an effective opacity of `.45` in relation to what lies underneath _both_ of those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Center text vertically by adding a line height, but the image would need a fixed height.

For the overlay, make the hover CSS completely visible, but the background on the original overlay transparent.

```
.img-overlay h3 {
    opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(255,254,254,1);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.img-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.700);
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow:hidden
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.bucket:hover .img-overlay {
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}
```

The entire overlay and all of its contents were being told that they should be transparent. By changing the RGBA of the background of the overlay to be transparent only, your text remains completely visible.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SdsJ9/135/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I wasn't able to reply until now. The transparency worked like a charm! For the vertical alignment, the images dont' have a fixed height because I wanted them to be responsive. Is there anyway to use line-height in that case? Also, what if the text is two-lines instead of one? Will that matter?